# Can't unzip a file in ubuntu sever

Tags: ubuntu, tar

Hy everyone,

I want to install Cassandra Apache on my ubuntu server. I get the file but when I try to extract the tar file I get an error. Please take a look at the print screen.

[image]

Can someone help me to get that ?

Comment: Please add error messages as text in your question (with code formatting) rather than as a screen shot. Text is easier to read, and can be searched in case someone gets the same error message in the future.

Comment: @EsembledINTL,Please take care of your question. Verify [the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36549965/5832518) posted to your question. Accept the answer if it resolves it. Put a comment, if you see any other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is tape archived and then compressed with gun zip format.

apache-cassandra-2.2.5-src.**tar.gz** ← <kbd>tar</kbd> + <kbd>gz</kbd>

#### decompress gunzip file

```
gzip -d apache-cassandra-2.2.5-src.tar.gz
```

### untar the outcome of above step

```
tar -xvf apache-cassandra-2.2.5-src.tar
```

Comment: root@dedi-fr-20388:~# gzip apache-cassandra-3.0.4-src.tar.gz
gzip: apache-cassandra-3.0.4-src.tar.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged

Comment: `gzip -d filename` should be the syntax for decompress. `-d` says decompress.

Comment: @EsembledINTL, has it been fixed ?